# How to selectively print plots from all plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, printing

I have a data frame which includes Block 1-9. After data processing, I need to print the plots for each individual Block (or partial of Blocks, like 1-3 or 1, 3, 5) but not print in the same graph. How can I use R to do this?

```
p1<-ggplot(data_final, aes(x=ChartID, y=FlMean, colour=Block)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#FF6666",
           position=position_dodge(width=NULL)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=FlMean-SD, ymax=FlMean+SD), width=0.4,
                position=position_dodge(width=NULL))+facet_wrap(~ Block)
```

This is what I can do to print all plots at once. How can I play with p1 to achieve my purpose?

Comment: `p1 %+% subset(data_final, Block %in% c(1, 3, 5))`?

Comment: It works. Thank you so much!